# (Linux Mint) - How to restart mono .exe upon crash

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have recently made a Tcp-server in mono develop c#.

My computer runs Linux mint 17

I run this server using `sudo mono Desktop/server.exe`
However it crashes every now and then, and I would like to make it restart upon crash, as I otherwise have to go home to my computer to restart it when it crashes.

I realize this is not a stable solution, but it'll do for now.

I've heard of UpStart, but couldn't really understand the documentation.
When I start my program through terminal I can't see any new processes pop up in System Monitor, so I don't know the name of the process of the program either.

(I have been searching around quite a lot, and tried upstart a bunch, but I've had no success with any of my tries. Not even finding the name of the servers process)

**Question:
Is there an easy way to detect if my program is running, and if not restart it automatically?**

Comment: Use some monitor/supervisor, for example supervisord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have recently made a Tcp-server in mono develop c#.

If you own the code, the best thing to do is to fix the code so it doesn't crash. The only times you want to restart something when it crashes is when you don't have the code or the manpower to fix an issue in the software you're using.

Comment: It is my own code, but the program is so very trivial and I only use it myself. Simply restarting it would be a good enough solution for me for sure. The problem that I would have to solve is waay to advanced for me (I've learnt after searching about). But thx for answering

Comment: if it's trivial, it should be easy to fix; just do a try-catch in your Main method  and call again your initialization logic

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, but I'm not sure I'll contribute with a universal answer:

My previous code involved a block of:

```
while (data != null) {
        sw.WriteLine (data);
        sw.Flush ();
        data = file.ReadLine ();
        }
sw.Close ();
file.Close ();
```

Where sw was a streamWriter.
The reason for it crashing was a fail at sw.Flush that i don't understand. I solved it with a try catch as suggested by knocte:

```
try{
    while (data != null) {
        sw.WriteLine (data);
        sw.Flush ();
        data = file.ReadLine ();
        }
    sw.Close ();
    file.Close ();
    }catch{
        sw.Close ();
        file.Close ();
        continue;
    }
```

Which isn't a great solution, but apparently better then restarting the application. Right now everything seems to be working good. Thanks

EDIT: Apparently knocte suggested that I'd put a try catch over my entire Main(), but this still works